# Blender 2.9: Can't select objects by clicking on them. Also can't pan with middle mouse and shift

Tags: 3d-view

Lumping these 2 together since they happened at the same time, and guessing it might be the same fix. But basically, I can't pan around my scene with the middle mouse and shift anymore, can't pan with the hand in the top right of the viewport, and I also cant select object by simply clicking on them, only by drawing a box over them, tweak select doesn't work either.

The camera moves and pans just fine but the normal view won't. Other scenes work just fine it's only this one that's being funky.

Comment: Go into "Preferences> Keymap" and, at the top where it says "Blender" the dropdown, see if that has changed for you.. How long has this been going on? Have you tried deleting the 2.9 preferences folder, restarting Blender and choosing your desired input method again? If it were me I'd check your inputs in the preferences to make sure something like "Emulate 3 button mouse" hasn't accidentally been enabled. It sounds to me as though Blender has, for some reason, switched to another input method of the three you can choose from at initial startup but I could be wrong.

Comment: I often find that's because I have one object in EDIT Mode, and so I can only click on parts of that object.  be sure you are in OBJECT Mode in your 3d viewport.

Comment: If it's that particular scene then maybe try saving it out as something else in a different folder and then re-open it. I think something similar happened to me a while back but saving it out as a new file and re-loading it seemed to fix the issue.